# Icons can't be seen on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS's  Launcher after updates

Tags: launcher

After updating yesterday, (can unfortunately not remember the specific updates) the launcher could not be made to appear. Rebooting the system showed the launcher only as a black bar at the left edge of the screen without any icons in the launcher.

If the mouse arrow is moved over the black launcher bar, the names of the applications next to the launcher appears. What could be done to have the icons to be visible in the launcher?

Comment: I got it working just by rebooting a few times.No extra efforts were needed.

Answer (score 1):

If it existed before, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type:

```
unity --reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Open terminal and run following command:

Rebuilt icon pack

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Unity-icon-theme'
```

Other default icon pack

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-dark' 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-light'
```

Hope this gonna help.